# AWS EMR psycopg2 module not found

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pip, psycopg2, amazon-emr

I am executing a spark job in AWS Elastic Map Reduce cluster. I had the same problem with `boto3`. However, I fixed that with my bootstrap script which is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo pip-3.6 install boto3
sudo yum update -y
```

I tried to do the same thing with `psycopg2` but it is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo pip-3.6 install boto3 psycopg2
sudo python3 -m pip install psycopg2
sudo yum update -y
```

`emr version: 5.29.0`

Comment: What is not working? Try [`pip install psycopg2-binary`](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/).

Comment: the above command should work, what is the error?